# I am trying to pass an ArrayList to a method in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to pass an ArrayList to a method in Java. But it gives me the error:

```
incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>"
```

Here is the code:

```
class hello
{
    public static void main()
    {
        List<String> iname = new ArrayList<>();
        iname.add("1");
        iname.add("2");
        iname.add("3");

        hello obj = new hello(); 
        iname = obj.changeName(iname); //<- problem here
    }

    public String changeName(List<String> iname){
        //...
        return "some String result";
    }
}
```

And it gives me the aforementioned error in this statement at "iname" in parenthesis:

```
iname = obj.changeName(iname);
```

Somebody please help me out.

Comment: The method returns `String`, iname is of type `List of String`. A box of eggs isn't a single egg. That is all there is to this.

Comment: Free reputation!!! Invite your friends, we need more answers!

Comment: @Pshemo See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373011/is-there-a-valid-close-reason-for-too-basic ... lost in action: a close reason.

Answer (score 4):

`iname` is `List<String>`, while the return type of method `changeName` is `String`.

If you want to return `List<String>`, you can declare it this way:

```
public List<String> changeName(List<String> iname){

    // ... you should return a List<String>  in this method
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method

```
public String changeName(List<String> iname)
```

has the return type **String** and you are trying to assign that String to a variable of type List when you do

```
iname = obj.changeName(iname);
```

That is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns String, but you are trying to assign return value to a List variable, so change it to

```
final String someString = obj.changeName(iname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns a simple String which is about to  be assigned to a List.
Change changename to `public List<String> changeName(...)` or use a new varible which is of type String and assign the return value.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `iname` is of type `List<String>` but you are attempting to return type `String` from your method `changeName(...)`.

You need to either update the method to return a type `List<String>`:

`public List<String> changeName(List<String> iname){ ... }`

Or change the variable the method is returned into like:

`String variable = obj.changeName(iname);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to store the return of your `changeName` function (a `String`) in the `iname` variable, which can only hold `List<String>`. This should work:

```
String result = obj.changeName(iname);
```

The alternative would be, to change the `changeName` to return `List<String>`, and change the function's implementation accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `public String changeName(List<String> iname){}` is returning a String instead of a list of Strings. Try `public List<String> changeName(List<String> iname){}` instead. The method changeName is trying to fit an entire list into a single String. If you left your program as it, then you would have to return a single item from your iname List back into the main method.